# Segregate rows according to their HEAD (parent) - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `SQL` table.

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| ID | TestNo | TestName | HeadID |  
+----+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     21 | Comp-1   |  null  |   
|  2 |     22 | C1       |  21    |   
|  3 |     23 | C2       |  21    |   
|  4 |     24 | C3       |  21    |   
|  5 |     47 | Comp-2   |  null  |   
|  6 |     25 | C4       |  47    |   
|  7 |     26 | C1+      |  21    |   
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```

I want to get all the child rows (according to their `HeadID`) below their head test.

`select * from ranges order by HeadID`

The **ACTUAL OUPUT** I get from the above query:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| ID | TestNo | TestName | HeadID |  
+----+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     21 | Comp-1   |  null  |   
|  5 |     47 | Comp-2   |  null  |   
|  2 |     22 | C1       |  21    |   
|  3 |     23 | C2       |  21    |   
|  4 |     24 | C3       |  21    |   
|  7 |     26 | C1+      |  21    |   
|  6 |     25 | C4       |  47    |   
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```

but my **DESIRED OUTPUT** is:

```
+----+--------+----------+--------+
| ID | TestNo | TestName | HeadID |   
+----+--------+----------+--------+
|  1 |     21 | Comp-1   |  null  |   
|  2 |     22 | C1       |  21    |   
|  3 |     23 | C2       |  21    |  
|  4 |     24 | C3       |  21    |   
|  7 |     26 | C1+      |  21    |   
|  5 |     47 | Comp-2   |  null  |  
|  6 |     25 | C4       |  47    |   
+----+--------+----------+--------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one level of children, then you can achieve this ordering like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Ranges
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN HeadID IS NULL THEN TestNo ELSE HeadID END
    ,HeadID
    ,ID
;
```